# How to click openHAB's login button using Playwright?

Tags: c#, playwright

I'm trying to click openHAB's login button using Playwright like this:

```cs
await page.GetByText("lock_shield_fill").ClickAsync();
```

This is how the page looks like (I'm trying to click the shield icon):
[image]

Clicking this button manually forwards me to openHAB's login page, but when using Playwright, it fails with the following error:

```
waiting for GetByText("lock_shield_fill")
  locator resolved to <i class="icon f7-icons">lock_shield_fill</i>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
    element is not visible - waiting...
```

I also tried `await page.Locator("css=a.color-gray").ClickAsync();` but the error is the same (except the located element).

Forcing this action via `await page.Locator("css=a.color-gray").ClickAsync(new LocatorClickOptions{Force = true});` does not solve the problem and gives the following output:

```
waiting for Locator("a.color-gray")
  locator resolved to <a href="#" data-v-57182fee="" class="button button…>…</a>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
    forcing action
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
```

How can I click the element using Playwright to get forwarded to the login page?

Thx!